# a pop up window which would display a webpage in it

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

I am new to android development, I am making an app which has a pop up window which would display a webpage in it. I have started working on it but I cant figure how to proceed. Following are the codes I used, so far completely errorless.

|| activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/aquamarine">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="TEST APPLICATION"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.07" />

</LinearLayout>
```

|| MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.two;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.android.two.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop);


        WebView wv = (WebView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.wv);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        dialog.show();


        Button btnDismiss = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }});
    }
}
```

|| pop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:id="@+id/wv"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dismiss"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="X"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wv"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example of a webview inside a DialogBox:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    alert.setTitle("Title here");

    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });

    alert.setView(wv);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as a popup you need to create another layout with the webview and a new class that extends from a **DialogFragment**. The dialogfragment has to inflate the new layout when created. Your main activity will only have the button in the layout.